# Multitouch Cocos2d TouchesBegan Individual vs Sets of touches

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, multi-touch, touchesbegan

I am designing an app and we're having some issues with multitouch tapping and slightly delayed multitouch tapping (which results in 2 individual calls to TouchesBegan).

The problem we have come across is when the player taps with two fingers at the same time:

Sometimes it can be registered as an NSSet with touches.count = 2

OR

Sometimes if the player is even slightly late on the 2nd touch, it will register two calls to CCTouchesBegan each with touches.count = 1.

What would be the easiest way to register both TouchesBegan calls with touches.count = 2 AND when the player is slightly late on the 2nd touch (two calls to TouchesBegan) with the same callback?

My initial thought was to get the [event timestamp] and compare that with the previous timestamp, then check to see if it is within a certain time interval...

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need timestamp comparison. Instead of using **touches** NSSet object you can utilize **event** to retrieve touches.

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if( [[event allTouches] count] == 2 )
    {
        // Do your thing here
    }
}
```

Note: If you tap with two fingers with a slight delay ccTouchesBegan will be called twice but in the second call **event** object will have two touches.

Comment: hey, thanks Sohaib! How long of a delay would it take then, for the event object to report 1 touch count, for a 2nd call to TouchesBegan?

Comment: I just tested it out and it seems that the event bundling is based on if you have your first finger held down when the 2nd finger hits down? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Are you trying to capture double tap with two touches?

Comment: basically we are trying to make a failsafe for the player so if they sloppily perform a multitouch (with two taps OR with the first finger held touching and then the 2nd finger slightly delayed touching down) it will still count as a multitouch.